# For $G$ an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup, is $[G : H]$ the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $ng \in H$ for all $g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup.

What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $ng \in H$ for all $g \in G$?

Is it $[G : H]$, or can it be strictly smaller (a divisor of $[G : H]$)?

Comment: Hint: Consider the Klein four group and the trivial subgroup.

Comment: The term you should look up is the "exponent" of a group, which can be smaller than the order of the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This already fails when $H$ is trivial group. Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the question I meant to ask (which I incorrectly reduced to the present question): [Compute the index of $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ in $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069235/compute-the-index-of-mathbfz-alpha-in-mathbfz-alpha-beta-gamma)